# make div larger than container

Tags: css, html

with the code below I am trying make "ThumbNails" as large as the contet (dynamic) requires and show (only) an horizontal scrollbar if not fitting in the contining div but I am failing.
What am I doing wrong?

html:

```
<body>
 <div id="Fascione"></div>
 <div id="Wrapper">
  <div id="Menu"></div>
  <div id="Contenuto">
   <div id="VariableImg"></div>
   <div id="Back"></div>
   <div id="Next"></div>
   <div id="ThumbNails">
    <img><img><img>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="Footer"></div>
</body>
```

css:

```
body{width:1024px; margin:0px auto;}
div#Fascione{width:inherit;min-height:125px;border-bottom:2px solid black;}
div#Wrapper{width:inherit;padding:8px 0px 4px 0px;}
div#Wrapper{width:inherit;padding:8px 0px 4px 0px;}
div#Menu{float:left;width:200px;}
div#Contenuto{overflow:hidden;margin-left:208px;}
div#Back, div#Next{width:49%;cursor:pointer;text-align:center;margin:1% auto;border:1px dotted #1111cc;background-color:#ffffff;}
div#Back{float:left;}
div#Next{float:right;}
div#Back:hover, div#Next:hover{border:1px solid #1111cc;}
div#ThumbNails{clear:both;max-height:180px;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden;background-color:#f0f0f0;}
div#Footer{clear:left;width:inherit;} /* clear left needed in combination with the overflow:hidden of Contenuto */
```

**Edited**: removed old, invalid link.

Comment: I would actually like to achieve the same look as the posted css code in this question...

Comment: I think you have just mixed up your `overflow-x` and `overflow-y`. `overflow-x` is horizontal and `overflow-y` is vertical - so you want `overflow-y: auto` and `overflow-x: hidden`.

Comment: no, no; I really want it to scrol horizontally and not vertically; the problem is that with my code the pictures go to the next line and the scrollbar does not appear at all.
I tried also the `white-space:nowrap;` and to use `overflow-x:scroll;` with no success.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I misunderstood the problem. When I add `white-space: nowrap;` to `#ThumbNails` in Firefox 10 then it works for me.

Comment: well, yes, I tried it once again and `white-space:nowrap;` works... I must have had some other mistake when I tried it last...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @My Head Hurts the proper answer is to add `white-space:nowrap;`.